# Hibernate does not return first record from database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I build a Spring Boot app with Oracle 19c as database. I've created entities based on tables in database and some simple endpoint using Spring Data Rest and JPA, but when call database for all records it returns data starts from the second record, and when I try to access the endpoint that gets id as path variable to retrieve single object an error occurred.

I used Postman to test my rest controllers. Spring Data Rest with users/1 returns nothing and 404 status. EntityManager entering URL returns also nothing but status is 200. When I try to call the method from JpaRepository findById() in my controller it shows error 500.

#### User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String username, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

   // setters/getters
}
```

#### Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;


    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // setters/getters
}
```

#### UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

#### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:placeholder
spring.datasource.username=placeholder
spring.datasource.password=placeholder

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

#### UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> getAll() {
        List<User> users = entityManager.createQuery("from User", User.class).getResultList();
        System.out.println(users);
        return users;
    }

    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) {
        System.out.println("Sended id: " + userId);
        return userRepository.findById(userId).get();
    }
}
```

#### Error message

```
Sended id: 1
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_0_, user0_.name as name2_2_0_, user0_.password as password3_2_0_, user0_.username as username4_2_0_ from user_table user0_ where user0_.id=?
2020-09-19 15:48:27.350 ERROR 18860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present] with root cause

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at springboot.resources.UserController.getUser(UserController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at springboot.resources.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$344055f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at springboot.resources.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a0145449.getUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

#### Results from Postman:

UserController.java:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjU0D.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c2Da.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y95hl.jpg

Auto-created endpoints from Spring Data Rest:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C51nG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx6mV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xokah.jpg

Data in database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTied.jpg

Have suggestions to solve this?

Comment: What you mean by first record, all other records are coming?

Comment: Exacly, I can do POST, GET and other actions, but can't get record with id 1

Comment: do you get the record with `id = 1` in GET all users?

Comment: Ok got this. It's all about commit in database...  It's because I created first record manually in DB and not commit this. My fault. Thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 0):

remove @Transaction, hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am aslo a novice programmer in `java`, however I will try to answer  as per my experience,

Repository `findById` returns `Optional`, so when you use directly `userRepository.findById(userId).get()` and the corresponding `userId` doesn't exists then exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException` occurs.

When you use `Optional` make sure you check first if the value is present and then use `get`. Change `getUser` method to,

```
@Transactional
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) {
 
Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
return user.ifPresent() ? user : null;
}
```

Further I would suggest to use `Response` object to return specific `HttpStatus 404` incase `userId` doesn't exist which is standard way to query `byId` operations.

Comment: You're right. First I should check if the value is present, but my problem is that I have the value with id 1 in the database and I couldn't get to it. Thanks for your opinion anyway.

Comment: @PeterStuck, Yes I was trying to answer the initial problem mention in the question. But anyway coming back to your problem, Do you have unit test for the repository in place ? You can easily check this whether the repository gives data or not .

Comment: @PeterStuck, in the first image of postman `https://imgur.com/f56A1Ln` call you posted for getAll() there is no user_id with `1` ...Why ?

Comment: Actually, I've already discovered this bug. It was a simple commit,  previously I was working on MySQL where it is not necessary. Thanks for tips!